# How do I include exceptions in node winston daily rotating log?

Tags: node.js, logging, winston, uncaught-exception

I am trying to create a daily rotating log with log entries from throughout the application as well as uncaught exceptions:

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston')
import 'winston-daily-rotate-file'
const httpContext = require('express-http-context')

const requestIdFormat = format((info, opts) => {
  const requestId = httpContext.get('requestId')
  if (requestId){
    info.requestId = requestId
  }else{
    info.requestId = ''
  }
  return info
})

const allTransport = new transports.DailyRotateFile({
  filename: 'logs/%DATE%-application.log',
  datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  maxSize: '20m',
  maxFiles: '14d',
  level: 'info',
  handleExceptions: true
})

const errorTransport = new transports.DailyRotateFile({
  filename: 'logs/%DATE%-error.log',
  datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  maxSize: '20m',
  maxFiles: '14d',
  level: 'error',
  handleExceptions: true
})

export const logger = createLogger({
  format: format.combine(requestIdFormat(), format.timestamp(), format.printf(i => `${i.timestamp} | ${i.requestId} | ${i.level}: ${i.message}`), format.errors({stack: true})),
  transports: [
    allTransport,
    errorTransport,
  ],
  exitOnError: false
})
```

But the exceptions e.g. `throw Error('hello?')` are not logged to the log files.

I've tried other variations c.f. https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#handling-uncaught-exceptions-with-winston e.g. setting exceptionHandlers in createLogger, but that does not work either.

How should I alter the code to include uncaught exceptions in the log?

UPDATE: I now see that an exception thrown on e.g. invalid import IS in fact logged, so maybe the issue is that the exception I test with is thrown in an express service - maybe it is caught in the express framework and that is why it is not logged?

Thanks,
-Louise

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just "manually" logging exceptions, i.e. logger.error(err), as I already have a middleware hook for showing a catch-all error page.

I am still not sure why some exceptions were automatically logged and why I have to manually log exceptions I explicitly throw via "throw new Error('some message')"?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this kind of situation before, and for some reason, sometimes the node process get killed/exited before all log handling finishes its execution. There are some libs that may cause conflict in handling because they may call process.exit() while other libs are trying to handle the same thing. So, we need to investigate and debug to try to find what is terminating our process before our logs are flushed/written to disk. I strongly recommend not doing any async processing when caughting exceptions. Do everything in a sync way and faster.
In a project I've worked, I spended hours until I found process.exit in a module , probably copied from internet. Process.exit been called everywhere in an app is the root cause for errors and misbehavior of apps.